# How often is it acceptable to time out when pinging google?

Tags: ping

I am trying to resolve some lag spike issues and have pinged googled, I am probably timing out once every 15-25 pings or so, does this indicate a problem or should I look elsewhere? I have a packetloss of 1%, I assume this is too low to be the cause of the spikes?

Comment: Are you pinging google.com or one of their public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4)? 
Either way, I'm pretty sure all of Google's properties are load balanced and so I'd expect to pretty much never lose a ping.  Ok, in the real world maybe not **never** but more or less. I'm pinging google continuously as I'm writing and got to 331 packets sent with 0 lost.  Avg RTT 11ms, max 21ms.

I wouldn't expect packet loss of 1% to be the *cause* of your "lag spikes"  but I think that you're seeing an indication of a problem.
Do you see packet loss ONLY pinging google or other sites/addresses too?

Comment: And what about pinging the gateway directly?
Cable/fios/dsl/other?  Combo modem/router?  Type?  (if not combo, type of each)

Perhaps your router is aging/not keeping up with the broadband and it's introducing the latency.  Perhaps the modem is starting to go and introducing the latency.  I've seen this go many ways.  Process of elimination is your friend.  Unless you're on a generally 'unstable' connection like satellite or far-from-the-CO dsl, you shouldn't see any noticable packet **loss**.

What are your round trip times and how many pings are you sending when you see 1%?

Comment: Okay, first of all, thanks a bunch for the help. I am a functional illiterate in this stuff, but here goes, I have a wireless router (I think?) and I am on wi fi currently, in my apartment. How do I go about pinging the gateway directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a basic home setup (like I assume yours is) the router is the gateway.  So if you know the router's address (often something like 192.168.0.1) just ping that directly.

If you don't know the router's address and you are on Windows, open a cmd prompt, type `ipconfig` and in the output find the adapter that is connected (will be named something like `Wireless LAN adapter Connection 1` or similar) and in there find the line that says `Default Gateway`.  That is your gateway address and that's what to ping.

Comment: Okay got it! 0% packet loss min ms: 1 max ms: 91 and average ms: 4. Sometimes the ms spikes to mid forties or so but I doubt this is the problem. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Ok, if I read that right you got a ping response as high as 91ms.  Is that right?

Let's try this again but this time using a switch for continuous ping (I'm assuming you're on Windows, yes?)

Type `ping -t 192.168.0.1` (or whatever your gateway IP is) and let that run for at least 50 - 100 pings.  Then hit ctrl+c to stop it and share those results.

Comment: Okay packets sent: 301, 0% lost, min ms: 1, max ms: 20, average ms: 1.

Comment: Ok.  That's much better than the last time when you reported a ping of 91ms.  To be sure, are you doing this from the same location in your house each time?  You said you're on wifi.  Where you are in the house in relation to the router/access point and walls and stuff between you affects the signal.

Now try to `ping -t www.google.com` and let that run a hundred pings

Comment: Packets: Sent = 185, Received = 180, Lost = 5 (2% loss), Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 85ms, Average = 4ms. I got two packet loss in a row that approximately corresponded with a large lag spike I had. Could this be the issue? Okay I got another lag spike that coincided with the time out.

Comment: If you're on wifi, wire up & test again. Looks like your have interference on the wifi. Neighbours/microwave etc

Comment: There are still factors but I would look to my ISP for issues.  Take a few of these extended pings to different sites (google, msn, facebook, amazon for example) and show them to your ISP.  If it's a cable service, you could be having modem issues.  Let them check signal levels but also, if signals are good and you still have issues, you might try swapping the modem out (they can progressivlely fail quietly).

The other thing you can do is do `tracert google.com` (or whatever other target site) and that will show which hop in the chain is the slow hop/problem.

Comment: Take a few of these to each site, take screen shots of each and use them as evidence to your isp that there is a problem.

You can (should) also do this from a  wired connection if possible to rule out your wifi as an issue though you got a pretty good result above even on wifi.  However doing it on a wired connection will eliminate that as something your ISP can blame.  They will often point the finger in every direction but theirs.
Good luck.

Comment: You are the man! Thank you very much! Kinda weird tho that it just started happening all of a sudden like 2 days ago.

Comment: Could be a temporary issue with your ISP, could be your modem starting to fail, could be configuration changes ISP made upstream that are a problem.  Many variables.  But it's 95% or more that the problem is upstream from your network so take it to the ISP with the evidence and let them deal with it.

Glad I could help